# Multiple APs in one room

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

Test office : 10m² ~ 33m² (Station device will need to  detect a AP signal from adjacenct office

Quantity of APs : 60-80

Distance between APs:  10cm ~ 2m ~ 10m

Antenna use: Direction, Omni direction. 5dBi (pole), 12dBi (panel), 18dBi (panel)

Basically the test setup is as above. I observed that the Client is not able to associate with the AP device. Even if they are associated, it would be unstable sometimes.

Is this because of the interference?
Or any other possible cause?

Comment: Are they 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz? I'm guessing they're also all configured for maximum power, too?

Comment: Thanks @grawity for the response. the AP are transmitting in 5GHz (802.11 n) frequency. Is there any limitation of AP quantity in a room?

Comment: I did reduce the Tx power too on those surrounding APs, but the result is just the same.